# Automatic Nodetitles: How to hide "Pattern for the Title" when empty

Tags: 7, nodes

I installed [Automatic Nodetitles 7.x-1.0](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) on Drupal 7 for Staff Content Type. Everything seems perfect except the feature "**Pattern for the title**" for "**Automatically generate the title and hide the title field**".

The pattern I replaced with "**[node:field-firstname] [node:field-middlename] [node:field-lastname]**, but it displayed the ***ACTUAL TEXT*** "**[node:field-middlename]**" on title when middle name is empty. **Is there a setting or solution to hide pattern when empty?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `-dev` version of the module. The release date for 1.0 of autmoatic nodetitles is `2011-Jun-07`. You really think something released in 2011 is bug-free in against Drupal 7.31 (current stable release) ...

If you really care you could request a new supported release of the module in the issue queue.